# JavaScript is secretly running on my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My only line in the routes file is this:

```
root :to => 'spikes#index'
```

In the Javascript assets I have a simple function like this:

**spike.js file:**

```
$(function(){

    alert("WAT");
    document.write("abc");

});
```

In the Views->spikes->index.html.haml file I have NOTHING! it is empty.
I used to have the following code, but I removed it:

```
  = javascript_include_tag 'spike'
```

But still when I run my Rails app, I see an alert and "abc" written on the browser.

Where is it calling it from? What on earth!?!

UPDATE: This is also my **application.html.erb file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>D3Spike</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `<script>` tag in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (or maybe `.haml`, not `.erb`), which wraps all your pages. If you take that out for a second, you'll probably see the alert go away.

A couple things to understand: 1) the JavaScript code you showed us runs just by virtue of being included (paste it into a console in your browser to see what I mean) and 2) in Rails, the normal behavior is for all your JavaScript to be included all the time, which is perhaps not what you expected.

Comment: hmm I updated my question with the contents of that file. Do you see anything suspicious in it? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's normal. Take out `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`, save the file and refresh the page.

Comment: I also added a little more detail in my answer that might help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, I took out that avascript_include_tag "application" part from it and yes now it is not getting called. But now in the haml of my page that was empty I posted this: Now should it call anything ? cause it doesn't :   = javascript_include_tag 'spike'

Comment: I wouldn't put JavaScript includes on individual pages. I would stick with the Rails default of having a `javascript_include_tag` in `application.html.erb` and make it so your JavaScript only gets called where you need it.